# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar milisegundos en minutos y segundos? JavaScript / Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, datetime, javascript-metodo

Tengo que mostrar una cuenta regresiva basándome en una variable que me llega en milisegundos. Tengo 1.000.000 de mili segundos, son 16 minutos y 40 segundos, ya hice una función que me convierte esos mili segundos a minutos y segundos y devuelvo esas dos variables minutos y segundos.

Esta función me devuelve 16 minutos y 40 segundos, el problema es que me los devuelve como un entero 1640.

```
const milisegundosAMinutosYSegundos = (milisegundos) => {
  const minutos = parseInt(milisegundos / 1000 / 60);
  milisegundos -= minutos * 60 * 1000;
  const segundos = milisegundos / 1000;
  return Number(`${minutos}${segundos}`);
};
milisegundosAMinutosYSegundos(1000000)
```

```
  function countDown() {
    let timer = 1640 //Lo que me devuelve la función de arriba.
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (timer === 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
          timer--
          console.log(timer)
          return timer;
        }
      }, 1000);
  }
```

La cuenta regresiva comienza en 1640, lo que yo quiero conseguir es que sean minutos y segundos y no un entero. Entiendo que es así por la forma en que estoy devolviendo esos valores, pero aunque los pase por separado no veo la manera de que la cuenta regresiva arranque en 16 minutos y 40 segundos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de la función `countDown` se puede mantener todo en milisegundos y en cada ejecución descontarle `1000`. Y la función `milisegundosAMinutosYSegundos` se puede usar para convertir los milisegundos actuales al formato `HH:mm`

```js
const tiempoInicial = 1_000_000;

const milisegundosAMinutosYSegundos = (milisegundos) => {
  const minutos = parseInt(milisegundos / 1000 / 60);
  milisegundos -= minutos * 60 * 1000;
  const segundos = milisegundos / 1000;
  return `${minutos}:${segundos}`;
};


function countDown() {
    let timer = tiempoInicial 
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (timer === 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        } else {
          timer -= 1000 // descuento de un segundo
          console.log(milisegundosAMinutosYSegundos(timer))
          return timer;
        }
      }, 1000);
}
countDown()
```

Comment: Ahí funciona perfectamente, mil gracias por responder!!